# RSS новости в android 2.2 и android 2.3 работают, но начиная с android 3.0 не работают

Tags: android, rss

Выдает эту ошибку в logCat:

```
Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> null //android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Именно, начиная с androin 3.0 не работает, в ранних версиях работает. Где именно мне искать подводные камни?

Comment: > Где именно мне искать подводные камни?
В [документации][1], как ни странно. Ну и имя исключения говорит само за себя.

  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: самое интересное, что rss то к вопросу никак не относиться. Но подобный вопрос сильно популярный. Поэтому предлагаю выносить NetworkOnMainThreadException в теги и метить все подобные вопросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы работаете с сетью в главном потоке. Вам нужно создать отдельный поток и там работать с сетью. С 3 версии андроид запрещает работать с сетью в главном потоке

Comment: Тогда почему в ранних версиях работает?

Comment: До 3 версии это было разрешено